# Unable to start the daemon process. how can I solve it please

Tags: java, android, android-studio, gradle

### Unable to start the daemon process.
This problem might be caused by incorrect configuration of the daemon.
For example, an unrecognized jvm option is used.
Please refer to the User Manual chapter on the daemon at https://docs.gradle.org/6.5/userguide/gradle_daemon.html
Process command line: C:\Program Files\Android\Android Studio1\jre\bin\java.exe -Xmx2048m -Dfile.encoding=UTF-8# -Duser.country=US -Duser.language=en -Duser.variant -cp C:\Users\Acer.gradle\wrapper\dists\gradle-6.5-bin\6nifqtx7604sqp1q6g8wikw7p\gradle-6.5\lib\gradle-launcher-6.5.jar org.gradle.launcher.daemon.bootstrap.GradleDaemon 6.5
Please read the following process output to find out more:

---

Check the JVM arguments defined for the gradle process in:

- gradle.properties in project root directory

i tried to change "org.gradle.jvmargs=-Xmx2048m" to "org.gradle.jvmargs=-Xmx1024m"
and deleted file gradle
nothing worked

Comment: Hello, I don't know much about this but you can try to reinstall the android studio.

Comment: Try to decrease to Xmx512m and for sure rebuild project

Answer (score 3):

[you can go to gradle.properties](https://i.stack.imgur.com/GpA6A.png)

go to file version and gradle properties, open it and change with this `org.gradle.jvmargs=-Xmx1024m` next you can sync the gradle and ready to build run.